# How to return after startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get my application to return after a startActivity function. I don't need anything to return, I just need the application to continue on at the same point that the startActivity is called, reason being I'm looking for a change in them magnetometer, and then when detected the application can continue.
I haven't found any way to do this, I tried startActivityForResult as well but nether works. Is there some way to define setup either startActivity, or startActivityForResult so that it will return to the point of calling it ?
Or some other way to do this.
Ive spent many hours trying different methods and none have worked, please help Ive run out of ideas.

```
 private void scanStart() { // was private added static
   //
    snloop=0;
    if (startscan != 1) {
        final Intent msens = new Intent(this, MldpBluetoothScanActivity.SensorActivity.class);                                         // Added by Chris
        msens.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivityForResult(msens,snloop);
    }
   startscan =0;
 public static class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mMagnetometer;
    private final float[] mMagnetometerReading = new float[3];


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    }
  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Don't receive any more updates from sensor.
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    // Get readings from accelerometer and magnetometer. To simplify calculations,
    // consider storing these readings as unit vectors.

  @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float axisX = event.values[0];
        float axisY = event.values[1];
        float axisZ = event.values[2];

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();                                                       //Get the ActionBar

        //  if (snloop == 0) {
        if (axisZ > lastZ + 500 || axisZ < lastZ - 500) {
            actionBar.setTitle("greater than 500");                                              //Set the title on the ActionBar
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);                                                    //Make home icon clickable with < symbol on the left to go back
            setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);                                                          //Make the progress bar indeterminate
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);                                                //Make the progress bar visible
            snloop = 1;
            lastZ = axisZ;
            startscan =1;
            onPause();
           else {
            actionBar.setTitle("Please Place on Interchange Point");                                              //Set the title on the ActionBar
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);                                                    //Make home icon clickable with < symbol on the left to go back
            setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);                                                          //Make the progress bar indeterminate
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);                                                //Make the progress bar visible
            snloop = 0;
            lastZ = axisZ;
        }
```

Comment: `I just need the application to continue on at the same point that the startActivity is called`. If you have coded al right then there is no further code after the statement startActivity(). The activity is probably killed when your activity goes to background. This is a normal life cycle process for activities. You should override onSaveInstanceState to save the instance variables of your activity. Then get them back in onCreate() for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish activity use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("SOMETHING", "EXTRAS");
this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And then you will get result here in your parent activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == request_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String returnedResult = data.getData().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, from the responses I think there is no direct way to return, but that I need to move all code after result into or called from the onActivityResult method. No other way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable write the exact code here for you because of being away from android studio right now. but explain the flow.

override the method `onActivityResult` in your activity from where you are calling `startActivityForResult`.

It will give you the `requestCode`, `resultCode`, and Intent(with data or without). requestCode will be as same as you sent it with `startActivityForResult`